# Netbeans doesn't show errors in rows

Tags: java, netbeans

I stopped to see errors in my Java project in Netbeans. I only cannot see in in one project, all others projects are ok. How can I fix it?

[image: project]

Comment: Close the project, close Netbeans, open Netbeans and try to open project again (File menu).